# adjusting the color of a segment of a color Image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing a face swapping. I have done it but Its final step is not finished.the photos have different brightness. I don't know I should correct it. I need your help. I'm not going to blur the image. I also tried to equalize their histogram before swapping but it didn't get a good result. thank you.[to see the image click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qriqG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need seamless cloning:

1. https://github.com/alyssaq/face_morpher
2. http://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think seamless cloning mixed the images while I want to change the face. the result of seamless cloning is similar to the both images. and I don't like it.

Comment: Take a look here : http://www.compvision.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/965-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85/

Comment: I meant the images, they are were made using the sources I mentioned above (with minor changes).

Comment: you're right, the pictures have swapped very well. excuse me, could you please send me its source code? thanks.

Comment: Source as I mentioned: https://github.com/alyssaq/face_morpher  you need correct facemorpher/warper.py method test_local() you need to change blended_img = blender.poisson_blend(dst_img1, dst_img2, mask) to blended_img = blender.poisson_blend(dst_img1, base_img, mask). I have no ready to use sources, but it is simple to correct ones from github.

Comment: excuse me, It's a very long source code and I have done most of its methods in another way. and I'm not going to change my code.